# Is there a standard format for the videoFrameSize property?

Tags: video, schema.org, structured-data

I'm about to add structured data to a page type that contains video data, and after looking at the documentation at schema.org about [`VideoObject`](http://schema.org/VideoObject) I see that the field [`videoFrameSize`](http://schema.org/videoFrameSize) should be of type `Text`.

Now I wonder if there is some standard or prefered format to supply this, like `[height]x[width]` or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Youtube declare

```
<div itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/VideoObject">
  <meta itemprop="playerType" content="HTML5 Flash">
  <meta itemprop="width" content="480">
  <meta itemprop="height" content="360">
```